# ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipException: Wrong Local header signature: 0xE011CFD0

Tags: c#, excel, npoi

I have a problem with NPoi.

I need to read an xlsm file, locally the code works fine, but on the server have error: Wrong Local header signature: 0xE011CFD0

Anyone have any idea what may be causing this error?

Comment: A header signature lets an app quickly check whether it is reading a file with the expected file format.  NPoi requires a file in the OpenXML format.  It didn't get one, as you can tell from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures), it got an .xls file, not a .xlsm file.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error message when I was trying to open an excel file which has been protected with a password which the code was not aware of:

```
string sFileExtension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).ToLower();
ISheet sheet;
string fullPath = Path.Combine(newPath, file.FileName);
using (var stream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create))
{
    file.CopyTo(stream);
    stream.Position = 0;
    if (sFileExtension == ".xls")
    {
        HSSFWorkbook hssfwb = new(stream);
        sheet = hssfwb.GetSheetAt(0); 
    }
    else
    {
        XSSFWorkbook hssfwb = new(stream); //This line threw the exeption
        sheet = hssfwb.GetSheetAt(0);  
    }
}
```

Problem solved by removing the protection of the workbook - did no try to decrypt it in the code.

Comment: Exact same error, but in my case it wasn't an encrypted .xlsx file, it was simply "protected from editing". Opening the file in Excel, clicking "Enable Editing" and then saving the file allowed the same code that had been throwing the exact error to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you open the file with the extension is .xls, use HSSFWorkbook, and if .xlsx, use XSSFWorkbook. Hope it solves your problem.